# Bat file for moving files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I want to create one `bat` file that will move files from one location to one backup folder. Condition is I need to move all folders which are older than 30 days inside parent directory. Name of folder is creation date of folder.

For example: 
All files of 17 October 2012 would be there inside folder named 10172012.Source folders are:

```
C:\Data\DataIn\Processed\10172012

C:\Data\DataIn\Processed\09172012

C:\Data\DataIn\Processed\08172012
```

So on today bat file should move folders "09172012", "08172012" to destination backup folder:

```
D:\Backup\Processed\
```

Comment: Does this *have* to be done in Batch? PowerShell would be significantly easier (date-manipulation is difficult in Batch).

Comment: Can you assume "there will always be directories for the last 30 days present, and no other directories?"  If so, you could avoid explicitly checking the dates, just make the batch file list all the directories in order newest-first with 'dir', loop until you've seen 30 directories with 'for' and then anything seen after that, move it to the backups.

Comment: @lessthanideal: Actually I can not assume this thing. If there is no other solution I am getting I have to go with your suggestion.

Comment: Can you have these named as YYYYMMDD, instead of current order? that would make it easier to sort?

Comment: This [link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetime.php) has some code for date addition/subtraction.

Comment: @anishsane: I will check out the link. Format of folder can not be changed as these folders are created by one third party application running on machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using shell scripting it was easier to do. Finally I implemented this using shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Get Julian Day number of today's date
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set /A m=1%%a %% 100, d=1%%b %% 100, y=%%c
)
set /A A=(m-14)/12, todayJDN = (1461*(y+4800+A))/4 + (367*(m-2-12*A))/12 - (3*((y+4900+A)/100))/4 + d - 32075
rem Process all folders
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   rem Get Julian Day Number of this folder
   set folder=%%a
   set /A m=1!folder:~0,2! %% 100, d=1!folder:~2,2! %% 100, y=!folder:~4!
   set /A "A=(m-14)/12, folderJDN = (1461*(y+4800+A))/4 + (367*(m-2-12*A))/12 - (3*((y+4900+A)/100))/4 + d - 32075"
   rem Move folder if it is older than 30 days
   set /A daysOlder=todayJDN - folderJDN
   if !daysOlder! gtr 30 move %%a D:\Backup\Processed\
)
```

Julian Day Numbers are described here: http://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm

Comment: Should I keep this bat file in source folder and then execute? Because after doing this response coming is: "/12 was unexpected at this time".

Comment: Oops, my mistake! Enclose in quotes the whole large expression of second `set /A` command into the `for` loop. I already do that in the code above...